# Deploy Meteor.js app by running `mrt` or `meteor`

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteorite, demeteorizer

Why are Meteor.js apps not deployed by uploading to a server by doing the following:

1. Install `npm`
2. Install meteor `$ curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh`
3. `meteor create myApp`
4. Upload Meteor code files from development system
5. Deploy using `meteor`

And instead deployment guides are instructing us to convert Meteor apps into node.js modules using demeteorizer and manually installing Mongo etc which are much more tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`meteor deploy` will deploy your app on meteor's free hosting infrastructure. It's a cool way to show your app to the world, but it isn't intended for serious production use. That's why you'll find a lot of articles detailing how to deploy on your own infrastructure (essentially this is what goes on behind the scenes with `meteor deploy`). Yes, it's a lot more complicated, but that's expected with a little DIY.

People are using demeteorizer because most existing node.js [PAAS solutions](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Node-Hosting) don't know how to run meteor apps. So, for example, if you want to run on [nodejitsu](https://www.nodejitsu.com/) you'd use demeteorizer to turn your app into a "standard" node.js application, as shown [here](https://properapp.com/meteor/hosting-a-meteor-app-on-nodejitsu-2/).

In the future, MDG will be creating a platform known as galaxy which will be an easy-to-use production environment (kind of like heroku for meteor, but better).